# Apache Tika with Encrypted PDF

Tags: adobe, apache-tika

I wanted to extract PDF content using Apache Tika Library. All is good until I encountered PDF with encrypted username and password. 
It hits errors as below:

> INFO  Document is encrypted
>   org.apache.tika.exception.EncryptedDocumentException: Unable to process: document is encrypted
>     at org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:153)
>
> Caused by: org.apache.pdfbox.exceptions.CryptographyException: Cannot find an appropriate security handler for Adobe.APS
>     at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.decrypt(PDDocument.java:952)
>     at org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:139)
>     ... 4 more

Does anyone knows if Apache Tika supports extraction of PDF with such security feature?

Comment: You might ask on the PDFBox user list: users@pdfbox.apache.org

Comment: Hey @fattysxx, did you find a solution or do you have any updates?

Answer (score 0):

You can try it below. It worked for me

PasswordProvider pp = (metadata) -> "password";

```
    // Create a context parser for the pdf document
    ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
    context.set(PasswordProvider.class, pp);
```